# Problems with Heroku. MODULE_NOT_FOUND,

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am developing a project in nodeJS and I am deploying it in Heroku, but I found this problem: requireStack:  [ '/app/src/db.js', '/app/src/index.js' ].

I have been researching for 2 days and I cannot find the solution. I think the problem is with the directories, I have tried a thousand ways to call my index.js file in my Procfile, but Heroku keeps giving me the same error.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance, greetings!

This is my Procfile in the root of my repository folder

```
web: node ./src/index.js  && try too->  web: node src/index.js
```

This is my index.js file in the root of my src folder.

```
const express = require("express");
const db = require("./db.js");
const app = express();
const router = require('./router');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(router);

db
.then(() => {
  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Node server runing on http://localhost:${port}` 
));
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

My db.js file in the root of my src folder.

`````
````
const config = require('./config/config.json');
const {Sequelize, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE || config.development.database,
process.env.MYSQL_USER || config.development.username,
process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD || config.development.password,
{
       host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST || config.development.host,
       port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT || config.development.port || '3306',
       dialect: 'mysql',
       operatorAliases: false,
       pool: {
          max: 5,
          min: 0,
          acquire: 30000,
          idle: 10000
      },
    }
  );
  module.exports = sequelize.authenticate()
 .then((db)=>{
  console.log('MYSQL connected');
  return db;
  });
 ```
`````

Comment: what is the command you have added for "scripts" -> "start" in package.json ?

Comment: Hi Vishnusaran, use the following "script" ->     "start": "node ./src/main/index.js"

Comment: Alejandro, didn't you try changing Procfile like web: npm start ?

Comment: Hi @vishnusaran, I changed the Procfile back to -> web: npm start but still can't implement it on Heroku. Keep crashing, I get this error requireStack: ['/app/src/db.js', '/app/src/index.js']